# How do I make window visiable/invisible at runtime?

Tags: python, kivy

I am using kivy to create a small Gui for my python program. This Gui is not always visible. So I start it with these settings:

```
Config.set('graphics', 'borderless', True)
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', False)
Config.set('graphics', 'window_state', 'hidden')
```

However: Somewhere in my program I want to make the window visible again. How do I do that? I couldnt find anything that changes configuration at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that if you are using the SDL provider you have a **hide & show** functions on the Window object

from the kivy.core.window docs:

```
hide() Added in 1.9.0
Hides the window. This method should be used on desktop platforms only.

Note
This feature requires the SDL2 window provider and is currently only supported on desktop platforms.

show()¶Added in 1.9.0
Shows the window. This method should be used on desktop platforms only.

Note
This feature requires the SDL2 window provider and is currently only supported on desktop platforms.
```

Comment: cool! thats working. Any ideas on how to bring the window to the front? :P

Comment: A comment on the link I posted discusses focus not being set, it says:
"I can confirm this is happening to me too. I have to put .show() twice for it to work as expected."

Comment: That did not work for me. But `Window.minimize()` + `Window.restore()` did the trick - what a hack... why is there no `focus()` method?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Kivy, but it looks like you just need to set it to visible.

`window_state`: string , one of 'visible', 'hidden', 'maximized' \
                    or 'minimized'

from:
https://kivy.org/docs/_modules/kivy/config.html

Looking at this github post: https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/3637

The method they're using is .hide() and .show().

Comment: As I said in my question: simply changing the Config at runtime does nothing

Comment: Sorry, didn't comprehend that at the time.